# why do need to set propties for Dynamic partition in hive

Tags: apache, hive, hive-partitions, hive-configuration

I would like to know one thing in hive dynamic partition. While doing dynamic partitions we have to set following properties

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
```

Without those properties we can't do a dynamic partition.

I want to know why these are required? 
Can someone tell me why we need to set this properties.

Answer (score 0):

It was done as additional protection measure against partitions being unintentionally overwritten.

[Docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert) says:

> Another situation we want to protect against dynamic partition insert
>   is that the user may accidentally specify all partitions to be dynamic
>   partitions without specifying one static partition, while the original
>   intention is to just overwrite the sub-partitions of one root
>   partition. We define another parameter
>   `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=strict` to prevent the all-dynamic
>   partition case. In the strict mode, you have to specify at least one
>   static partition. The default mode is strict. In addition, we have a
>   parameter `hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true/false` to control whether
>   to allow dynamic partition at all. The default value is false prior to
>   Hive 0.9.0 and true in Hive 0.9.0 and later